# Using more threads slower than one in Julia

Tags: multithreading, julia

I have the following code in a script `foo.jl` to perform a simple parallelizable task (it may seem very mundane, but is effectively similar to a crucial task in my research):

```
using LinearAlgebra
using Statistics

N = 60
length = 200

function matOps(mat1, mat2)
    mat = mat1'mat2 - mat2'mat1
    eye = Matrix{Float64}(I,N,N)
    for i in 0:10000
        mat = eye*transpose(mat)*eye
    end
    return mat
end

y = zeros(length)
println("Number of threads: $(Threads.nthreads())")
@time Threads.@threads for i in 1:length
    mat1 = rand(N,N)
    mat2 = rand(N,N)
    y[i] = mean(matOps(mat1, mat2))
end
```

So all this does is perform some (pointless) operations on a 60x60 matrix 10,000 times, then take the mean of the matrix elements and store it in an array `y` of length 200. So we loop over this 200-length array and for each element we do this matrix operation chain, and store the single mean value.

This is very parallelizable since each iteration is completely independent of each other, but running the loop with more threads is actually slower. Below is some output:

```
$:> julia foo.jl

Number of threads: 1
184.268869 seconds (9.85 M allocations: 107.718 GiB, 5.16% gc time)

$:> $env:JULIA_NUM_THREADS=2
$:> julia foo.jl

Number of threads: 2
377.960229 seconds (9.85 M allocations: 107.583 GiB, 71.04% gc time)

$:> $env:JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4
$:> julia foo.jl

Number of threads: 4
1121.259542 seconds (9.84 M allocations: 107.190 GiB, 94.31% gc time)
```

This actually gives me a speedup using `Distributed` and `SharedArrays` instead of `Threads`. Its also my understanding that `Threads` is experimental so I understand if this is just something that's being worked on. Just thought I'd check if I'm doing something wrong, since just looking at how the time is scaling it seems each thread is doing the entire loop sequentially.

I am using Powershell on Windows 10, Julia version 1.0.3

Edit: I changed the matrix operation from `eye*mat'eye` to `eye*transpose(mat)*eye` since it messed up the syntax on here. Its the same since mat is real.

Comment: You should start by reading the performance tips: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/index.html  In particular, you are using global variables, and you are also measuring compile time instead of just runtime. Put your code in functions, call them from inside the REPL, and use BenchmarkTools instead of the `@time` macro. Also, at least up to version 1.2, `rand` is not thread-safe and should be outside the threaded loop.

Comment: BTW, `length` is a *very important* built-in function, so it's not advisable to overwrite that.

Comment: @Bebotron - the easiest thing to fix `rand` problems is to fence generation of `mat1` and `mat2`, which is a fast step in your procedure, with a locks. In Julia 1.3 `rand` will be thread safe by default.

Comment: Well in my actual research this is done in functions with no global variables, I was just trying to find the easiest way to replicate the problem. But sure, even when putting everything into a `function main()`, and bringing the `rand` declarations outside of the loop, I still get the same slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this (note that we have a separate RNG for each thread):

```
using LinearAlgebra
using Statistics
using Random 

println("Number of threads: $(Threads.nthreads())")

function matOps(mat1, mat2, N)
    mat = mat1'mat2 - mat2'mat1
    eye = Matrix{Float64}(I,N,N)
    for i in 0:10000
        mat = eye*transpose(mat)*eye
    end
    return mat
end
matOps(rand(2,2), rand(2,2), 2) # on rare occassions 
                        # multithreaded compiling fails

function get_y(N, L, rands)
    y = Vector{Float64}(undef, L)    
    Threads.@threads for i in 1:L
        mat1 = rand(@inbounds(rands[Threads.threadid()]),N,N)
        mat2 = rand(@inbounds(rands[Threads.threadid()]),N,N)
        y[i] = mean(matOps(mat1, mat2, N))
    end
    y
end

const N = 60
const L = 20

const rands = [MersenneTwister(i) for i in 1:Threads.nthreads()]
@time get_y(N, L, rands);
@time get_y(N, L, rands);
```

One thread:

```
> julia foo.jl
Number of threads: 1
 15.137731 seconds (958.56 k allocations: 10.771 GiB, 9.40% gc time)
 12.788418 seconds (800.34 k allocations: 10.763 GiB, 7.24% gc time)
```

Two threads:

```
> julia foo.jl
Number of threads: 2
  8.573475 seconds (958.52 k allocations: 10.767 GiB, 14.13% gc time)
  7.947657 seconds (800.25 k allocations: 10.756 GiB, 12.73% gc time)
```

Comment: Do you get consistent results? As in is using 2 threads consistently giving those times compared to 1 thread? Also, are you getting a speedup using more threads? I have exactly what you suggested but sometimes it's fast and other times it's not, and using 4 threads slows it down a lot.